# Javadoc for Gradle API in Intellij IDEA

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

How to configure Intellij IDEA to pick Gradle API documentation and sources?

I have installed gradle-5.4.1-all.zip. In IDEA, I have chosen "Use local Gradle distribution. Yet, IDEA doesn't show documentation (ctrl+q) for any gradle api like task, repositories, etc. It also doesn't navigate to the original source  on clicking (ctrl+b) the api.  Instead, it decompiles the class and then shows this version.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This works for me. Have you trigger a re-import in gradle tool window? Please show screenshots with your Gradle settings and the screenshot with the problem.

Comment: @Andrey screenshots added.

Comment: Do you have this very Gradle build.gradle file imported in IDE project? What is the content of `apps/gradle` folder? Are there any errors in log: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085 Have you trigger re-import in Gradle tool window?